# How to compare date timestamp between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the scenario, to compare two date timestamps from different tables and have to take the most recent date from the first table, if  table 2  date > table 1 date then i don't want to take that date. I want to take the first table maximum date with timestamp of whole row..Please suggest how to achieve it..

Table1

```
CS. No.       Date.                          
C1.         01/10/2018 04:10     
C2.         24/08/2019 05:45
```

Table 2

```
S.no.     CS.No    Date
A1.          C1.       01/10/2018 04:05
A2.           C1.      28/08/2018 04:00
A1.           C2.      25/08/2019 03:00
```

Output table:

```
 CS.No.          Date.                  Timestamp
C1.       01/10/2018 04.10.    4.10
```

Comment: I simply do not understand.  Where does the `Timestamp` column from?  What happens to `C2.`?

Comment: @Gordan Linoff the timestamp column from the date column i have to take the timestamp which one should be maximum compare with two tables.

Comment: @susang i have edited my question.. i don't want to take the second table date only

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you can `UNION` both the tables and then use aggregation to get the maximum timestamp.

```
SELECT [CS. No.] [CS.No],
       max([Date.]) [Date.]
       FROM (SELECT [CS. No.],
                    [Date.]
                    FROM [Table1]
             UNION ALL
             SELECT [CS.No],
                    [Date]
                    FROM [Table2]) [x]
       GROUP BY [CS. No.];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `cast` as below

```
select a.*, cast(b.[date] as time) [timeStamp]
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on b.csno = a.csno
and cast(b.[date] as date) = cast(a.[date] as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare which timestamp is bigger between two tables based on the date_timestamp column, you can modify the previous query to include a comparison expression in the SELECT statement. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT 
    table1.date_timestamp AS table1_timestamp, 
    table2.date_timestamp AS table2_timestamp,
    CASE 
        WHEN table1.date_timestamp > table2.date_timestamp THEN 'table1'
        WHEN table2.date_timestamp > table1.date_timestamp THEN 'table2'
        ELSE 'same'
    END AS bigger_timestamp
FROM 
    table1
JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.date_timestamp = table2.date_timestamp;
```

This query adds a CASE expression to the SELECT statement that compares the two date_timestamp values and returns the name of the table that has the bigger timestamp. If the timestamps are equal, the ELSE clause returns the string 'same'.

Note that this assumes that the date_timestamp column in both tables has the same data type. If the data types are different, you may need to cast one or both columns to a common data type before comparing them.